# jquery drag image into text and show url of that image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, drag-and-drop

I have a textbox, a div, and an image.

Do we have any way to do like this:

1. When I drag that image into the div. (The image don't need to move, just like we left click on it, and drag it to anywhere, but it never move.)
2. The div show the image. (Duplicated 1 image into the div)
3. The text show URL of that image.

Do you have any idea or article(s) on doing this thing?

I've never coded drag drop in my life, but I know **Step 2** is just set HTML for the div, and **Step 3** is just get image src. However, on **Step 1**, how do I know when **"the image into the div and the mouse release?"**

I know [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com), it's not the dragable from [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com), cause the draggable makes object move. *I don't want it move.* Can you try click on any image on this *stackoverflow* website, or any link. Then you hold your mouse and drag it. Try drag a link into the search box at top, and you get the link. Thats what I want. Not the dragable of [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com) to make the object move.

Comment: Did you try? It might be simpler than you think...

Comment: Nah. I never code on drag and drop in my life. So, I don't know where I should start or read. That why I ask for idea or article for reading or doing this one.

Comment: You don't know where to start? The answer to that question is always "The Documentation" http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: I know jQuery UI, it's not the dragable from jQuery, cause the dragable make object move. I don't want it move. Can u try click on any image on this stackoverflow website, or any link. Then u hold your mouse and drag it. Try drag a link into the search box at top, and u get the link. That what I want. not the dragable of jQuery UI

Comment: Well, what is it the draggable from? You've provided no details so how can anyone possibly be expected to help you?? In addition, jquery draggable allows you to leave the original in its place while dragging. See this url and try dragging the top grey boxes around. http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

Comment: Dragging an image into your address bar  is a function of the web browser, not JS or the page you are viewing. You will want to use jquery draggable or something like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all of this with the dragable feature in jQuery. I noticed in a comment you mentioned that you don't believe this will work because it actually moves the image but there are more than just the default options! Take a look at the clone helper attribute.

Here's about as close of an example as there is and it sounds like you already know how to handle the rest (getting the src attribute, etc.).

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#method-option

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `draggable` allows you to leave the original in its place while dragging through the use of `Helpers`. See this url and try dragging the top grey boxes around. The two on the right use helpers, leaving the original in place.

http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

Using this in conjuntion with the [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#method-option) `Artsemis` provided will do the trick

Dragging an image into your address bar is a function of the web browser, not JS or the page you are viewing. You will want to use jquery draggable or something like it.